# App using AsyncTask still hogging the UI thread?

Tags: android, android-intent, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I've written an app that sits in the 'Share via' menu (for quickly emailing myself links to things I find on the web or look at in RSS readers) For this I'm using an intent.action.SEND intent-filter:

```
    <activity
        android:name="uk.co.baroquedub.checkit.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
           </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Here's the MainActivity package, it grabs the page title and url from the Intent and uses a separate GMailSender class to directly email me this info:

```
package uk.co.baroquedub.checkit;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private static Dialog dialog;

String title;
String url;
String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP );
    String action = intent.getAction();

    // if this is from the share menu
   if (Intent.ACTION_SEND.equals(action)) {   
           title = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT);
           url = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

           // Flipboard fix (remove title in URL)
           url = url.replace(title, "");

           if (url != null){
            url = title+"\n"+url;
           } else {
            url = "error getting URL";
           }

    // Asynch Task
                doSendTask task = new doSendTask();
                task.execute(new String[] { url });   

   }

}

protected void showDialog (String response){
dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);
    dialog.setTitle(response);

    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View view) {  

            dialog.dismiss();   
            finish();
        }  
    });

    dialog.show();
}

private class doSendTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";

      String senderPassword = getResources().getString(R.string.senderPassword); 
      String senderEmail = getResources().getString(R.string.senderEmail); 
      String recipientEmail = getResources().getString(R.string.recipientEmail); 
      String subjectText = getResources().getString(R.string.subjectText);

      GMailSender sender = new GMailSender(senderEmail, senderPassword);
      try {
        sender.sendMail(subjectText,   
                url,   
                  senderEmail,   
                  recipientEmail);
            response = "Email sent";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e); 
            response = "Error sending email";
        }

      return response;
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            showDialog(result);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    /*
     * Kill application when the root activity is killed.
     */
    UIHelper.killApp(true);
}

}
```

Version 1 worked fine but I was sending the email from within 'onCreate' which meant that until the "Email sent" notification appeared, the phone's browser would be unresponsive (I wasn't able to scroll or navigate to a new page). I then changed the code (as per above) to place the email sending code inside an AsyncTask class - but although the app still works the browser remains unresponsive until the dialog appears. AsyncTask seems to have made no difference.

Can anyone explain why, and hopefully suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1):

**ANSWER?**... I've massively simplified the above code to try to work out what might be wrong. I created a bog standard App and used the following:

```
package uk.co.baroquedub.testcheck;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    doSendTask task = new doSendTask();
    task.execute(new String[] { "urlString" });
}

protected void showDialog (String response){
    Toast.makeText(this, response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    finish();
}

private class doSendTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";

      try { 
          Thread.sleep(5000);
          response = "Waited";
      }
      catch (InterruptedException ex) {  }

      return response;
    }

    @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            showDialog(result);
    }
}

}
```

This has allowed me to see what's going wrong: my app is opening on top of the browser (a white screen appears with a title bar showing the name of the app) I wasn't aware of this with my proper app (above) because I was using a Theme that used a transparent background.

See: [screencast for demo of problem](http://screencast.com/t/NbTOxcLJxu)

So although the email is being sent as an AsyncTask, while this is happening the app itself is appearing on top of the browser - which is what is stopping it from being accessible. (I'll post a request for help on this as a separate question)

Comment: Here's the related follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13728628/share-via-application-that-runs-without-a-view

Comment: It kind of made sense with the assumption I had made: you are creating an Activity, which is effectively a new screen. I would've expected it to have a white background, and that would've made it obvious.

Comment: I was going to suggest using a service to run the code (I thought of that before, but I wasn't sure if you needed to show a pop-up, so I dismissed it), and someone did just that on the related question you opened.

Comment: Also, I'm not the biggest expert on Intents, but why are you checking if the intent is really a SEND? Doesn't the Intent Filter take care of that already?

Answer (score 0):

No, AsyncTask is not bond to your UI thread and you will not be blocking it as you did while doing some lengthy operation in your `onCreate()`.

Comment: ok, yes - what you say is what I'm expecting to happen but unfortunately the browser does stop being scrollable while the email is being sent - even as an AsyncTask. Can you think why that might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a mistake in your code:

```
 doSendTask task = new doSendTask();
 task.execute(url); // if you want to put more urls  task.execute(url,url1,url2);
 try {
        sender.sendMail(subjectText,   
                url[0],             // get the first url
                  senderEmail,   
                  recipientEmail);
            response = "Email sent";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.e("SendMail", e.getMessage(), e); 
            response = "Error sending email";
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but it's not clear what your recommendation is. Do you mean that I should recast the variable 'url' as an array, rather than a string, so that I can pass multiple URLs? Actually the string works just fine for me and the app works well - except for stopping the web browser from being scrollable while the email is sent.

Answer (score 0):

ASyncTasks are, indeed, executed on their own thread, as written on their [reference page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

When you create the intent for this activity, you pass the flag 'FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP', which reads something like '...all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.'. Doesn't this mean that the old activity is locked until this new one terminates?

Comment: Thanks for the good suggestion. I can't quite remember why I put that flag in (probably just copied a code snippet from somewhere). I tried commenting out that line but unfortunately the same problem is still occurring - browser freezing while the email is being sent :/